# Aggregate lists associated with list of items to single list in Java pre-java8

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guava

I have a list of items where each item in the list has a list of items associated with it.  I.e. I have a list of parent objects which have an instance variable of a list of child objects. I am trying to find an efficient way to aggregate all the items in the child lists to a single list in Java.  I have to do this using Java7 functionality because this is for an app on google app engine which does not currently support Java8.  I am sure there has been an answer to something like this but I am having a difficult time searching for it.

So I have a list of Objects which say correspond to an Order and each Order has a list of line items associated with the order.  I want a list of all of the individual line items associated with each of the orders in the parent list

Comment: Do the children have children too?

Comment: The children are objects they have instance variables that are lists too

Comment: Ok so it sounds like you have some sort of tree and you want to make a list of all the leaves? There are many possible orders so I think you should give a sample input and your desired output.

Comment: It isn't a tree.  I'll try to clarify it better by editing my original post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More efficient method of aggregating items into super list Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921264/more-efficient-method-of-aggregating-items-into-super-list-java)