# More efficient method of aggregating items into super list Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guava

I am looking for a more efficient way of accomplishing the result of the following code pre java 8 (this is on an app hosted on Google App Engine which does not yet support Java 8)

```
 List<Order> orders = getOrders();
 List<LineItem> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();

 for (final Order order : orders) {
     for (final LineItem lineItem : order.getItems()) {
        lineItems.add(lineItem);
     }
 }
```

Is there a more efficient means of accomplishing this without needing to use Java 8 functionality?  Possibly using Guava

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 List<Order> orders = getOrders();
 List<LineItem> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();

 for (final Order order : orders) {
     lineItems.addAll(order.getItems());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more efficient by avoiding the resize operation required by `ArrayList` when it hits the backing array size, and that's by calculating the size required before inserting.

```
int size = 0;
for (Order order : orders) {
 size += order.getItems().size();
}
List<LineItem> lineItems = new ArrayList<>(size);

for (Order order : orders) {
   lineItems.addAll(order.getItems());
}
```

Although this would scan `orders` twice, it can perform better if `getItems` are big and the backing-array need to be copied several times during resize.

Comment: Seems like a micro-optimization which clutters your code, so I'd not go this way unless you expect couple million elements in final list (even then I'd guesstimate the size). Additional code lines aren't worth it.

Comment: @Xaerxess how would you guess? Throw a magic number? The question asked about making efficient without specifying how big the list is.

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(expectedOrderSize * orders.size())`, if you get order (of magnitude) correct, you'd have at most 2-3 resizes, which isn't a big deal IMO.